# How to get correct scale factor for iPhone 6+?

Tags: xcode, retina-display, iphone-6-plus

When retina devices were introduced I started using this code in my apps:

```
int retinaMult = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

which would return `1` on a non-retina device and `2` on a retina device. I assumed it would return `3` on an *iPhone 6+* but I'm still getting a `2`. Is there something else I need to be doing?

Note: I tried `nativeScale` instead of `scale` and that returned the same numbers.

Comment: Did you enable native iPhone 6+ resolution be adding launch image?

Comment: @bpolat I had no idea that I had to set an explicit image for the launch image before this would work. If you want to make that the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add lauch images to enable native iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ resolution.

[image]